# What to place first: termination or pullup/pulldown?

Tags: ethernet, routing

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsY2m6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am routing some ethernet signals that have termination resistors as well as pulldown resistors, my question is that as the signal comes out of the chip, what should I place first - the termination resistor followed by pulldown, or have them both connect directly to the output?

Datasheet makes no mention of this sequence of resistors 
http://www.ti.com/product/DP83848I/technicaldocuments

Comment: What does the datasheet of the chip say ? Also first/last is confusing, make a drawing of what you mean by using the schematic editor which you can access when you edit your question.

Comment: If that area of PCB is smaller than t_risetime/20, its your choice. Risetime/20 is one metric of "too short a distance to store much energy".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie updated with schematic and part number, no mention of this sequence of resistors in the datasheet

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding. Both circuits don't make sense. First circuit doesn't make sense: "termination" resistor R2 is not terminating because MCU input is high impedance. Second circuit also doesn't make sense: that's just a voltage divider (that's not good unless the MCU input actually needs a lower logic level than the PHY chip is using).

Comment: I think you're not really routing the "ethernet signals" as these would come out of the PHY chip and connect the "magnetics" and then to the ethernet cables (with termination etc.). You're routing an **internal bus**. I doubt that that internal bus really needs to be terminated. I doubt this since most MCUs do not have the right output drivers for driving terminated signal lines.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf since [area]=\$m^2\$ and [t]=s we'd appreciate if you were to clarify this units mismatch

Comment: What should I make of this section in the Design and Layout guidelines: "To reduce digital signal energy, 50 ohm series termination resistors are recommended for all MII output
signals (including RXCLK, TXCLK, and RX Data signals.)", The pulldown is to set the PHY address.

Comment: @VanGo: so why do you think you need a pull-down resistor at any of the **output** lines ("to set the PHY address")?

Comment: I don't understand your question, there are pull downs on some of the RX lines to set the PHY address

Comment: 1. You said 50 Ohm series, but have 100. 2. 22-33 Ohms is more typical for series termination. 3. Both 100 series and 100 pull-down is a voltage divider. 4. If you want pull-down (rather than terminal), >= 1k is more appropriate.

Comment: @VanGo, you should use 2.2 kohms for these pull-downs, as shown in the datasheet, p. 37. Using 100 ohms will disturb their function as data pins.

Comment: @VanGo: your circuit diagram shows pull-down resistors (R1) at **outputs** of the IC in question (PHY chip). Why do you think you need them or who said you need them?

Comment: @curd Im now wondering the same thing, is there a difference as to where I put my pulldown? I assumed it was better for signal propogation if I put my pulldown close to the source since the signal will reach the intended voltage level sooner - not sure if this is the right logic.

Comment: @VanGo: as long as it is not clear **why** there are pull-down resistors there is no point in speculating which way is better. Maybe the eval board (linked in youthooth's answer) has them only for pulling the signal to a defined state when unconnected (obviously there is no MCU directly connected; the board schematic just shows a connector; no MCU).

Comment: @Curd "The DP83848VYB provides five PHY address pins, the state of which are latched into the PHYCTRL register at system Hardware-Reset."

Comment: @VanGo I would go with the termination first variant:
Your series termination and the impedance of the driver are building the actual termination resistor for the reflection coming back from your MCU. You should minimise the trace length between the PHY and the series resistor. Make sure to keep the stub to the termination resistor short.

Comment: @VanGo: i.e. they are **inputs** (that explains why there pull-down resistors make sense; but not for any of the Outputs; in your circuit diagram you showed outputs) and those inputs do definitely not need termination resistors as the signals on those lines are static (don't care after latching at reset). So either you need pull-down resistors (inputs) or you need termination resistors (outputs) or none but never both.

Comment: @Curd You are wrong. The RXD pins are outputs to the PHY in normal operation. They are only inputs when the PHY is in reset. The PHY address is latched when the reset of the PHY is released.
Source: Did 10+ designs contaning fast ethernet and gigabit PHYs

Comment: @Manu3I0us: ok, I don't know that chip. I assumed that the lines are either inputs or outputs; not both.  In that case it makes sense. It's strange that they use lines for input at reset and use the same lines as outputs in normal opertaion. Very strange! Can't they afford more pins or what?

Comment: @Curd It's not that strange, it's is used in a lot of chips like PHYs, CPUs, USB Hubs etc. It's used mainly for settings that need to be applied before the digital interface which allows the programming of the registers is running.

The technique is often called pin-strapping. each additional pin uses more board space and makes the finished device bigger and more expensive.

Actually, it makes sense to use the outputs of the device for pin-strapping, because so you can make sure no one is driving against them during the reset phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, I always look for related application notes or evaluation board schematics.

TI provides a [sample design schematic for the DP83848 chip](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/snlr022/snlr022.pdf), which shows the pull-down resistors on the MCU side of the signal (what you've labelled as "termination first"). The pull-down resistor should also be much higher than 100 ohm -- they suggest 2.2k ohm. And the source termination resistors will likely need to be lower than 100 ohm -- they suggest around 33-50 ohm.

TI's [design guide for their PHYTER products](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla079d/snla079d.pdf) also mentions (on page 8) that the source termination resistors are already included internally for the DP83849 and DP83640 chips (but not the DP83848 chip you've listed), so perhaps they could be viable alternatives to simplify your design.

Comment: That reference design shows how to wire the IC to an inter-board connector, rather than directly to an MCU.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, I'm not familiar with all of TI's evaluation boards, but I'm guessing that the design is intended to be an expansion card for one of TI's standard MCU evaluation boards. Obviously the PHY IC can't function by itself, so it must be connected to an MCU on the other end of that connector.